# How to typecast Object to another Class in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I want to typecast or change object type.

Here `dict` is `NSDictionary`

```
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

I'm getting this output : It is of Type: NSObject

```
{
 data1 =     (
                {
            lang = en;
            value = "ABC";
            },
            {
            lang = en;
            value = "ABC";
            }
        );

}
```

But I want it should be like this inside this parenthesis `( )`

It is of Type: NSDictionary

```
(
    {
     data1 =     (
                    {
                lang = en;
                value = "ABC";
                },
                {
                lang = es;
                value = "XYZ";
                }
            );

    }
)
```

Please help me I'm new to it.

Comment: Here, (  ) indicates array. So just add your dictionary to array.

Comment: This is not typecast. fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an array.put the dictionary in the array and print it.you will get the output you want.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict, nil];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to add your dictionary into array

```
NSDictionary *data1 =  @{@"data1":@[@{@"lang":@"en",@"value":@"ABC"},@{@"lang":@"en",@"value":@"ABC"}]};

NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:data1];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject: dict];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

Hope that solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same thing like this

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"name":@"abc",@"class":@"efg",}];
NSLog(@"array - %@",array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arrayOfDictionary = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dict];
NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfDictionary);
```

this will work.

Comment: @SucharuHasija I didnt get u